Python SDK Sol transfer error: Error sending transaction: 'result'
hello guys pls i get the error ( ERROR - Error sending transaction: 'result') in my below code, i'm making use of sol version 0.24.0 & python
def transfer_to_central_wallet(private_key: str, amount: float) -> bool:
try:
from_keypair = Keypair.from_secret_key(b58decode(private_key))
to_pubkey = PublicKey(CENTRAL_WALLET_ADDRESS)
    # Get recent blockhash
    recent_blockhash_resp = client.get_recent_blockhash()
    recent_blockhash = recent_blockhash_resp['result']['value']['blockhash']

    # Create transaction
    lamports = int(amount * 1_000_000_000)  # Convert SOL to lamports

    tx = Transaction(recent_blockhash=recent_blockhash)
    tx.add(
        transfer(
            TransferParams(
                from_pubkey=from_keypair.public_key,
                to_pubkey=to_pubkey,
                lamports=lamports
            )
        )
    )

    # Sign transaction
    tx.sign(from_keypair)

    # Send transaction with TxOpts
    opts = TxOpts(skip_preflight=False, preflight_commitment='confirmed')
    response = client.send_raw_transaction(tx.serialize(), opts=opts)
    logger.info(f"Transaction sent with signature: {response['result']}")
    return True
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f"Error sending transaction: {str(e)}")
    return False


The get_recent_blockhash RPC call was removed in v2 of the Solana validator. Be sure to update your solana-py library and use get_latest_blockhash instead:
    recent_blockhash = client.get_latest_blockhash().value.blockhash

Here's the source code for the new function, which comes with an example: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/2119e9da2f86f700730c69d86392243b5ef3dcea/src/solana/rpc/api.py#L690
